# How can I add a table column dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two arrays and need to write the data from both to two columns of a table. At this point I can write correctly data from the first array only and when I want to add the second array data, it gets added into rows.

`orderGelen` and `userNameArr` are my arrays. Here you can see my code:

```
for(let data of orderGelen){ 
   dataHtmlIds += `<tr><td>${data}</td>`;
}

for(let usr of userNameArr){ 
   dataHtmlUsr += `<td>${usr}</td></tr>`;

}

dataHtml = dataHtmlIds + dataHtmlUsr;
console.log(dataHtml);
```

And here I write that to table:

```
function tableConfig() { 

    tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
}
```

How can I make the second column `userNameArr` data?

Comment: Can you share demo?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put two arrays in one array like this

```
        const all = orderGelen.map((item, index) => ({ id: item, username: userNameArr[index] }));
        let html = '<table>';
        for (let row of all) {
            html += `<tr><td>${row.id}</td><td>${row.username}</td></tr>`;
        }
        html+='</table>'

        console.log(html);
```

Comment: Its working like charm but its make overwriting in previous datas. I can see only last data in table. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Yes but I already delete that html variable,  I directly add to my table. Its make again.

Comment: so right now you have table and you want to add `id column` and `username column` to this table ? or you want to add new `rows`  ?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
var dataHtml = "";
  for (
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    i < userNameArr.length || j < orderGelen.length;
    i++, j++
  ) {
    dataHtml += `<tr>`;
    dataHtml += `<td>${userNameArr[i] ? userNameArr[i] : ""}</td>`;
    dataHtml += `<td>${orderGelen[j] ? orderGelen[j] : ""}</td>`;
    dataHtml += `</tr>`;
  }
```

and you could write to the table like

```
  function tableConfig() {  
    tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
   }
```

Hope this helps